# WP8 IsTrial() always return false

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, trial

I've developed WP8 app with trial mode. All code around IsTrial() call was made as described in article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286402(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286402%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

When I debug app with a fake trial (as discribed at link above), my ad banner was shown ok on emulator and developer device, but when my app was became available in WP Store, it looks like IsTrial() always returns false - no ad is displayed!

Does anybody encounter the same problem?

Thanks to all!
With regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your App is working fine with license = true/false then after publishing App the code you have presented should work. The best practice is to put that code in Application_Launching and Activated events.
Note also that beta version is always free - so you also get false.

If you test IsTrial, you should also test IsActive. IsTrial returns true even after the trial period ends. [IsActive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.isactive) , however, will return false after the trial period ends.

Comment: Yes, my app works good when I simulate trial/full version in debug mode. The problem appears since app was became available in Store. Yes, I call IsTrial() in Application_Lauchning and Activated as described in MSDN article I mentioned above. I do not check IsActive() because I want to have unlimited trial period. I don't know, may I put my app name here to allow it to test

Comment: If you give unlimited trial period to user so why would he/she buy your app ? just try out this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Trial-Experience-Sample-c58f21af/view/SourceCode)

Comment: User should buy my app to hide Ad banner) Thank you for link, I'll check this sample.

Comment: I hope It may get helpful to you

Comment: @user3683136 Not really related, but an advice: If you just want to hide the ads in full version, make your basic version free (without trials and stuff) and provide an in app product to hide the ads. Users like to download free apps than to use the trial versions. You'll get more downloads this way.

Comment: @akshay2000, good idea, thanks!  
In sample there is the same IsTrial() call, but in another place.  My code in App.xaml.cs:<br/>'private void CheckLicense()
{
    #if DEBUG
       _isTrial = true;
    #else
       _isTrial = _licenseInfo.IsTrial();
    #endif
}<br/>private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    CheckLicense();
}<br>private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckLicense();
}<br/>if (((Application.Current as App).IsTrial))
     //Show Ad          
else
      //Hide Ad          
'<br/>OK during debug

Comment: Sorry, no line breaks for some reason.  I mean that this code works good during debug

Comment: I'm now checking my code - may be a problem does not directly connected with IsTrial() and the reason may be in Ad displaying routine.

Comment: IsTrial() works good. The reason of my problem was located in Ad displaying routine and appears only in some cultures, so it was hard to find. Thanks to all for help!